# How to change the HTML input type attribute from 'password' to' text'?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to change the HTML 'input' element 'type' attribute, from type="password" to type="text".

I am aware that it would be easier to find element by ID but not every page has the same id for the password input. How do I target the password inputs and change their inner value to a type of text.

I have this few lines of JavaScript code:

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
a.setAttribute(type,text);
```

Comment: Does it have to be in pure javascript? How about jQuery?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is an XY problem. What is the actual issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Note not all browsers support dynamically changing the input type, I believe IE below 9 will not let you

Comment: I would like to turn it into a clickable bookmark in Google Chrome. So jQuery wouldn't apply, just JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

To convert all elements of type password to text:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].type == 'password') arr[i].setAttribute('type','text');
}
```

Note: Not all browsers allow dynamic changes to the `type` attribute on inputs.

Comment: Note that if you check the _attribute_, you will need to check in a case insensitive manner. It's better to check the type itself (that is, `arr[i].type`).

Comment: Thank you very much, this method works perfectly so far!

Comment: @MrLister - Are you sure about that? [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) state: `When called on an HTML document, getElementsByTagName() lower-cases its argument before proceeding.`

Comment: @PM77-1 The case-sensitivity issue would be with the return value of `getAttribute()`, not the parameter passed to `getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice - the same story. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute): `When called on an HTML element in a DOM flagged as an HTML document, getAttribute() lower-cases its argument before proceeding.`

Comment: @PM77-1 The issue is the case of the return value, not the argument.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice - I *finally* realized that. Thanks.

Comment: @PM77-1 That's what I meant, yes. If the HTML has `type="PassWord"` then `getAttribute("type")` will return `"PassWord"`, but `arr[i].type` will be `"password"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get password field using the following query.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="password"]').type = "text";
```

If you're dealing with more than one field, you can use `querySelectorAll` And loop through them.

```
var pwds = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="password"]');
for (var i=0;i<pwds.length;i++){
pwds[i].type = "text";
}
```

Comment: That's the easiest if there is only one password input because it will only return the first one. Also it won't support IE < 8 though.

Comment: This is a good way to do it for modern browsers. Be careful, though, because it won't work for older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Unlike mine (now deleted) yours actually works. He is [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/88c731we/2/) as a proof.

Answer (score 1):

This transforms every input of type password into input of type text for a document.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="password"]'))
    .forEach(function (elt) {
        elt.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The function is called `document.getElementsByTagName` (with an s) and it yields a list of elements. So you will need to address it with an index (`a[0]` for the first input, etc.)

I think the problem is determining which of the inputs you will need to change though, if they're not marked with IDs.

Comment: This would be more complete if it addressed "How do I target the password inputs and change their inner value to a type of text."

Comment: It is a NodeList, not an array, although it is array-like in many ways.

Comment: Ok I understand it will get all the inputs thats found in the document, and put them into an array-like listing but how can i target just the one that is found to be: type="password"?

Comment: Just look for one that has the type attribute set to `"password"`.